# Error when trying to run selenium tests using geckodriver

Tags: selenium, geckodriver

- Firefox version = 53.0.3 (64-bit)
- Platform = Windows 10
- Selenium Version = 3.4
- Geckodriver Version = 0.16.1 (win64)

I'm trying to create a FF driver with the following setup method

```
protected WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeClass
    public void ffsetup(){
        FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
        options.setBinary("C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe"); 
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\Selenium\\Drivers\\FF\\geckodriver.exe");
        capabilities.setCapability("moz:firefoxOptions", options);
        driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
    }
```

When running this test using TestNG, a FF window opens, but nothing happens (test does not run). It will close after 45000 ms

```
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
Files\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\e10srollout@mozilla.org.xpi
1496266004087   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on e10srollout@mozilla.org version 1.14
1496266004088   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\firefox@getpocket.com.xpi
1496266004088   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on firefox@getpocket.com version 1.0.5
1496266004089   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\webcompat@mozilla.org.xpi
1496266004090   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on webcompat@mozilla.org version 1.0
1496266004092   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for XPIProvider
1496266004092   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: XPIProvider
1496266004092   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: LightweightThemeManager
1496266004092   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for LightweightThemeManager
1496266004092   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: LightweightThemeManager
1496266004093   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: GMPProvider
1496266004096   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for GMPProvider
1496266004096   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: GMPProvider
1496266004096   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PluginProvider
1496266004096   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PluginProvider
1496266004097   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PluginProvider
1496266004097   addons.manager  DEBUG   Completed startup sequence
1496266004429   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: <unnamed-provider>
1496266004430   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for <unnamed-provider>
1496266004430   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: <unnamed-provider>
1496266004610   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded
1496266004611   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   XPI Database saved, setting schema version preference to 19
1496266004611   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Starting timer
1496266004621   addons.repository   DEBUG   No addons.json found.
1496266004622   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1496266004623   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Starting timer
1496266004641   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PreviousExperimentProvider
1496266004642   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PreviousExperimentProvider
1496266004642   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PreviousExperimentProvider
1496266004644   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Starting write
1496266004666   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded
1496266004676   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Starting write
1496266004706   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded
[Child 5984] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file c:/builds/moz2_slave/m-rel-w64-00000000000000000000/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 346
[Child 5984] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file c:/builds/moz2_slave/m-rel-w64-00000000000000000000/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 346
1496266030506   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Add-on fxdriver@googlecode.com blocks e10s rollout.
1496266030506   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Add-on fxdriver@googlecode.com blocks e10s rollout.
1496266030507   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Add-on fxdriver@googlecode.com blocks e10s rollout.
1496266032435   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Add-on fxdriver@googlecode.com blocks e10s rollout.
1496266032435   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Add-on fxdriver@googlecode.com blocks e10s rollout.
1496266032436   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Add-on fxdriver@googlecode.com blocks e10s rollout.
1496266038481   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Add-on fxdriver@googlecode.com blocks e10s rollout.
1496266038481   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Add-on fxdriver@googlecode.com blocks e10s rollout.
1496266038483   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Add-on fxdriver@googlecode.com blocks e10s rollout.
1496266038587   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Add-on fxdriver@googlecode.com blocks e10s rollout.
1496266038587   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Add-on fxdriver@googlecode.com blocks e10s rollout.
1496266038588   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Add-on fxdriver@googlecode.com blocks e10s rollout.

    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:112)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:271)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:119)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:218)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:211)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:129)
    at com.tplus.auto.config.Driver.ffsetup2(Driver.java:42)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:564)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:213)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:138)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:175)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:107)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeClass ffsetup2
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe) on port 7055; process output follows: 
Files\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\e10srollout@mozilla.org.xpi
1496266004087   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on e10srollout@mozilla.org version 1.14
1496266004088   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\firefox@getpocket.com.xpi
1496266004088   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on firefox@getpocket.com version 1.0.5
1496266004089   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\webcompat@mozilla.org.xpi
1496266004090   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on webcompat@mozilla.org version 1.0
1496266004092   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for XPIProvider
1496266004092   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: XPIProvider
1496266004092   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: LightweightThemeManager
1496266004092   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for LightweightThemeManager
1496266004092   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: LightweightThemeManager
1496266004093   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: GMPProvider
1496266004096   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for GMPProvider
1496266004096   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: GMPProvider
1496266004096   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PluginProvider
1496266004096   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PluginProvider
1496266004097   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PluginProvider
1496266004097   addons.manager  DEBUG   Completed startup sequence
1496266004429   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: <unnamed-provider>
1496266004430   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for <unnamed-provider>
1496266004430   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: <unnamed-provider>
1496266004610   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded
1496266004611   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   XPI Database saved, setting schema version preference to 19
1496266004611   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Starting timer
1496266004621   addons.repository   DEBUG   No addons.json found.
1496266004622   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1496266004623   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Starting timer
1496266004641   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PreviousExperimentProvider
1496266004642   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PreviousExperimentProvider
1496266004642   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PreviousExperimentProvider
1496266004644   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Starting write
1496266004666   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded
1496266004676   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Starting write
1496266004706   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded
[Child 5984] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file c:/builds/moz2_slave/m-rel-w64-00000000000000000000/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 346
[Child 5984] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file c:/builds/moz2_slave/m-rel-w64-00000000000000000000/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 346
1496266030506   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Add-on fxdriver@googlecode.com blocks e10s rollout.
1496266030506   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Add-on fxdriver@googlecode.com blocks e10s rollout.
1496266030507   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Add-on fxdriver@googlecode.com blocks e10s rollout.
1496266032435   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Add-on fxdriver@googlecode.com blocks e10s rollout.
1496266032435   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Add-on fxdriver@googlecode.com blocks e10s rollout.
1496266032436   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Add-on fxdriver@googlecode.com blocks e10s rollout.
1496266038481   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Add-on fxdriver@googlecode.com blocks e10s rollout.
1496266038481   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Add-on fxdriver@googlecode.com blocks e10s rollout.
1496266038483   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Add-on fxdriver@googlecode.com blocks e10s rollout.
1496266038587   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Add-on fxdriver@googlecode.com blocks e10s rollout.
1496266038587   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Add-on fxdriver@googlecode.com blocks e10s rollout.
1496266038588   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Add-on fxdriver@googlecode.com blocks e10s rollout.
```

I have no issues running my tests using the Chrome and IE drivers, but cannot get FF to work.

Answer (score 0):

I have got same issue with latest version of Firefox.

Then I downgrade the Firefox and it get resolved.

I think this is compatibility issue with the latest Firefox version.

You can get rid of this problem by downgrading the Firefox version.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: What version did you downgrade to? I have tried the 2 previous versions, and it doesn't resolve the issue.